# rvest scrape multiple values per node

Tags: xml, r, css-selectors, rvest, magrittr

Taking this example XML

```
<body>
  <items>
    <item>
      <name>Peter</name>
    </item>
  </items>
  <items>
    <item>
      <name>Paul</name>
    </item>
    <item>
      <name>Claudia</name>
    </item>
  </items>
  <items/>
</body>
```

Question: What is the easiest way to get the following result?

```
"Peter"   "Paul"   ""
```

By now i achieve this as follows:

```
require(rvest)
require(magrittr)
my_xml <- xml("<items><item><name>Peter</name></item></items><items><item><name>Paul</name></item><item><name>Claudia</name></item></items><items></items>")
items <- my_xml %>% xml_nodes("items") %>% xml_node("item")
sapply(items, function(x){
  if(is.null(x)){
    ""
  } else {
    x %>% xml_node("name") %>% xml_text()
  }
})
```

To me this `sapply` construction seams like mistreating either `rvest` or css-selectors.

Comment: my answer is only slightly different than your approach, but it may be more of what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rvest` really isn't needed since this is pure XML (and you end up using `xml2` constructs anyway):

```
library(xml2)

doc <- read_xml("<body>
  <items>
    <item>
      <name>Peter</name>
    </item>
  </items>
  <items>
    <item>
      <name>Paul</name>
    </item>
    <item>
      <name>Claudia</name>
    </item>
  </items>
  <items/>
</body>")


sapply(xml_find_all(doc, "//items"), function(x) {
  val <- xml_text(xml_find_all(x, "./item[1]/name"))
  ifelse(length(val)>0, val, "")
})

## [1] "Peter" "Paul"  ""
```

(sometimes XPath can be better than CSS)

Comment: Thanks for the answer... unfortunatly this isn't a really more simple solution. Maybe someone else is coming up with a nicer approach. Thanks anyways

Comment: It's the best you're going to get since you want to capture the "missing" values. That's a node-by-node operation no matter what and mine is a tad more efficient since it doesn't have to do a CSS->XML conversion (`rvest` does that magically for you),  has fewer method dispatches (`rvest` routines just call `xml2` ones) and more efficiently gets at the `node`. So it actually is a more simple solution.

Comment: I think xml2 needs a better way to deal with this problem

Comment: Another possibility (it's still cumbersome) is to do `xml_find_all(doc, "//items[not(item)]")` which (for those who haven't misspent their youth staring at XPath constructs) will return all of the nodes without the desired sub-nodes (and then do processing that way). Prbly either a broader wrapper function would be needed in `xml2` _or_ the ability to specify an R callback function per node (that could then do more intelligent processing and return 'saner' things) since (sadly) there's no free lunch for this in the `libxml2`.